# Array editing not working correctly

Tags: php, arrays

OK so here's my code to edit a specific entry within the array, and the array layout is below.

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $listitem){

    if ($listitem[0] == $_POST['product']){
        if ($listitem[1] <= $_POST['remove']){
            $remove = array($listitem[0], 0);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$counter] = $remove;
        } else {
            $result = $listitem[1] - $_POST['remove'];
            $remove = array($listitem[0], $result);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$counter] = $remove;
        }
    }

$counter = $counter++;
}
```

Here's my `$_SESSION['Cart']` Array layout

```
Array( 


 - [0] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 0 )
 - [1] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 0 )       
 - [2] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 1 )

)
```

Either my understanding of the array is wrong with this line of code:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$counter]
```

Or my counter will not count:

```
$counter = $counter++;
```

since the only value it keeps editing the first entry [0]

Can anybody see where I've went wrong?

Comment: Change `$counter = $counter++` to `$counter++` or `$counter = $counter + 1` or `$counter += 1` or `++$counter` etc.

Comment: Please read about [increment and decrement operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, Idiot rookie mistake, that one thing has been baffling me for over an hour too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$counter = $counter++` will do nothing.

`$counter++` increments the value of `$counter`, but **evaluates** to its current value (the one it had before incrementing). That way, you're setting `$counter` to have the value of itself, and that doesn't usually do much.

Simply do `$counter++` instead.

(Additional info: there's also the pre-increment operator, `++$counter`, which increments the variable and returns it *new* value.)

Comment: It has a $counter = 0; above the foreach should that not work?

Comment: When you do `$counter++` it will increment the `$counter` by 1, but it will return the value it **was** before it was changed, so essentially, you are doing `$counter = $counter` or `$counter = 0`

Comment: @PirateScott Nope, the incrementing won't work no matter what the value is. Try it for yourself - execute `$i = 0; $i = $i++; echo $i;` and you'll see it's still 0.

Answer (score 0):

$counter = $counter++ will set $counter to its current value and then increment it by one.  It is a redundant statement.  If you do intend to just increment the variable $counter by 1 then just use $counter++.